# SOAP: Error Fetching http headers in PHP

Tags: php, soap

I am getting below error in SOAP request:

```
SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Error Fetching http headers in /var/www/mtes/public_html/application/libraries/banks_with_api/pnb.php:132
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('<?xml version="...', 'http://124.124....', 'http://tempuri....', 1, 0)
#1 /var/www/mtes/public_html/application/libraries/banks_with_api/pnb.php(132): SoapClient->__call('GetTransactionS...', Array)
#2 /var/www/mtes/public_html/application/libraries/banks_with_api/pnb.php(132): SoapClient->GetTransactionStatus(Array)
#3 /var/www/mtes/public_html/application/controllers/test.php(12): PNB->transaction_status('200815101030342...')
#4 [internal function]: Test->pnb_test()
#5 /var/www/mtes/public_html/system/core/CodeIgniter.php(359): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#6 /var/www/mtes/public_html/index.php(220): require_once('/var/www/mtes/p...')
#7 {main}
```

**What I tried?**

```
ini_set("default_socket_timeout", 120);
```

**CODE**

I want below xml as request to web service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
  <GetTransactionStatus xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <TxnReferenceNo xmlns="http://PNB_Inward_Remittance.RemittanceStatusReceive" />
  </GetTransactionStatus>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And for that, PHP code is below:

```
$location = WSDL_LINK;
$opts = array(
    'http'=>array(
        'user_agent' => 'PHPSoapClient'
        )
    );
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$client = new SoapClient($location, array("trace" => true, 'exceptions' => 1, 'stream_context' => $context,
                                          'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE, 'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1, 'connection_timeout' => 120));

$result = $client->GetTransactionStatus(array(
                    'TxnReferenceNo'=>$transaction_unique_id
                ));
highlight_string($client->__getLastRequest());
```

Comment: What headers do you get back when you just do a get one the service?

Comment: @symcbean: sorry, what do you mean by that?

Comment: I have edited my code.